# JS/Nodejs Where can I host images to get an api to show in a gallery page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, gallery

I want to upload some images to make a gallery and get an api so that I can fetch them and display on my webpage. Im learning nodejs/express and learned by now html css and JS... so im looking to make something simple just for the sake of the practice, and not have locally stored photos in the project file.
Ive looked into google developers console -> photos api, firebase & google cloud platform but I dont think its what im looking for (at least from Ive looked into), I just want to show my photos from a database, dont need any special features for them.
Perhaps Im missing somethig, if theres any other sites for it please refer, or if what im looking for DOES exist in  the google developer console id like to know where to look into, because im quite lost. tyvm ^^

Comment: Maybe some cdn sites suitable for you.

Comment: Upload them to your own site and then just write a node script that will return the image files in a folder you specify. You don't need a database or an API.

Comment: what do you mean by "upload to own site"? I upload the site to github, I want to avoid uploading the images there as well